# Derivative of max function

Tags: calculus

I was just wondering what the derivative of $f(x) = \max(0,1-x)^{2}$ would be. What technique do you use to determine this derivative?

Comment: Don't you mean $\max(0, (1-x)^2)$?

Comment: since $(1-x)^2 \ge 0 $ (for x a real number), $\max(0,(1-x)^2)$ is equal to $(1-x)^2$

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It might be of help to sketch the function or write it without the $\max$. We get
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-x)^2 & \text{if } x \leq 1\\ 0 & \text{if }x \geq 1\end{cases}$$
It is easy to work out the derivative everywhere except at $x=1$.
At $x=1$, work out explicitly from definition.
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \dfrac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} = 0$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \dfrac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^-} \dfrac{h^2}{h} = 0$$
Hence, we have
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2(x-1) & \text{if } x \leq 1\\ 0 & \text{if }x \geq 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: in your function definition for all x >= 1, you are returning 0. But let's take x = 2, then (1 - 2) ^ 2 will be (-1) ^2 which is nothing but 1 and according to op's max function, 1 should be returned. But since you gave the condition of x >= 1, we always return 0 even when x is something like 2. I think in comments what Andre Holzner said is correct. `since (1−x)2≥0 (for x a real number), max(0,(1−x)2) is equal to (1−x)2`

Answer (score 10):

HINT : Analyze this function on different intervals.

Comment: If x >= 1, f'(x) = 0, else f'(x) = -2(1-x)?

Comment: Now what happens when x = 1 ? Does f'(1) exist ?

Answer (score 5):

I would generalize this as follows:

Let

```
f(x) = max(0, g(x))^2
```

Then

```
f'(x) = [2*g(x)*g'(x)] if g(x) is > 0 else [0]
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but here an other way that can help.

It may be easier to apply the basic properties of derivatives on your problem knowing the following result $max\left \{ a;b \right \}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ and that $\frac{\partial |x|}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{|x|}=sign(x)$.

After all you need to do is to derivate: $(\frac{1-x+|1-x|}{2})^2$.
$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{1-x+|1-x|}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}2(1-x+|1-x|)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(1-x+|1-x|)=\frac{1}{2}(1-x+|1-x|)(-1+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(|1-x|))=\frac{1}{2}(1-x+|1-x|)(-1-sign(1-x))=...=(x-1)-|1-x|$ (different expression of the same function given above).

After you need to carefully check what happen at $x=1$ as allready explained above.